# executing a php script from a different location

Tags: php

I have a php script located in /var/log/myscript.php and i want to execute it from /home/user/run. I keep getting the following errors below. However if i go directly in the folder and run php myscript.php the script will execute. Strange, any suggestions. I have included the script bellow

PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: f in /var/log/myscript.php on line 73
PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/log/myscript.php on line 73

```
             <?php

$host = "some_destination";
$user = "postgres";
$pass = "postgres";
$db = "some_database";

$con = pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$db user=$user password=$pass");  

$line = 1;

$files = array();
$dir = opendir('.');


while(false != ($file = readdir($dir))) {
if(($file != ".") and ($file != ".."){
$files[] = $file;.
}
}

natsort($files); // sort.

foreach($files as $file){

if ( strpos($file,'syslog.1') !== FALSE )
{
echo "\n" .$file;

$f = fopen($file,"r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
$arr_to_insert = array();


while (!feof($f)) {
$group[] = fgets($f);
$line = preg_replace('!\s+!',' ', $group[0]);


$arrM = explode(' ',$line);

$month = $arrM[0];  
$day = $arrM[1];
$timestp = $arrM[2];
$src = str_replace("SRC=","",$arrM[11]);
$dst = str_replace("DST=","",$arrM[12]);
$spt = str_replace("SPT=","",$arrM[19]);
$dpt = str_replace("DPT=","",$arrM[20]);


if (ctype_digit($day)) {
if (ctype_digit($spt)){
if (ctype_digit($dpt)){ 
$sql = "INSERT INTO 





   logs(logmonth,logday,timestp,src,dst,spt,dpt)
   VALUES('$month','$day','$timestp','$
   $src','$dst','$spt','$dpt')";
   $res = pg_query($con, $sql) or die("Cannot execute query: $sql\n");
   $ar = pg_affected_rows($res);

 }
 }
 }

 unset($group);

}
}  
}
pg_close($con);
fclose($f);

?>
```

Comment: That means you never opened the file and `$f` did not get set.

Comment: Because you have relativ paths set, use the magic dir constant to prefix your paths/ filenames. http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: Thanks  Simon Müller, for pointing me in the right direction. This helped in resolving my problem.